# How can I port my program written in C++ (depends on Boost Library) and compiled with Linux GCC, to Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, boost

I have written a program in C++, which uses Boost Library (a c++ library used for various functions, from networking, computing to multitasking). I need to make that program work in windows.

What is the shortest path? I can find boost library for windows, and compile my code against that library, or I can rewrite my program in Java (boost functionalities I use already exists in java)?

Comment: Try first and tell what's wrong.

Comment: You're in luck, Boost is portable!

Comment: MinGW might be useful: http://www.mingw.org/

Comment: We've got programs that compile on Windows and Linux at the same time, using Boost. No problem at all.

Comment: You can install boost on windows as given [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html). If you want to have Linux like environment then go for CyGwin or Mingw .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Boost library exists for Windows. See: [Boost Getting Started on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html).

Comment: I downloaded boost library from the official site:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#the-boost-distribution

I have an Eclipse CDT (C++) project created in Ubuntu. I downloaded Eclipse CDT for Windows and made it work.
I guess, when I:
1) Transport my Eclipse project to Eclipse in windows
2) Modify the INCLUDE and LIBRARY paths as in the include and library paths inside the bundle, it would work...
But, the bundle does not have a "lib" directory as it mentions in the documentation!

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but I believe you have to build the Boost libraries. I had written a short post on this here: http://gigionit.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-build-boost-libraries.html but you should be able to find additional help if you do a little searching on StackOverflow or Google.

Comment: I try to execute "bootstrap" bat file, but it runs into an error related to a toolset parameter. The output in bootstrap.log file is:

Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
Please consult bootstrap.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bootstrap.log in that case.

The link file provides a download file for Boost version 1.52

Comment: Yes, you may run into some issues and need to install some build tools or set configuration. However people here aren't going to give you step-by-step instructions. As I said, do some Googling.